# enumitem: customized labels break `labelindent`

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, enumitem

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, showframe, lipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, label=\bfseries label \arabic*.]
\item \lipsum[66]
\item \lipsum[75]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt]
\item[\bfseries label] blah blah
\item[\bfseries long label] blah
\item[\bfseries long long label] \lipsum[75]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I'm hoping to align labels from a list to the left boundary, and `labelindent=0pt` produces exactly what I want.

But it doesn't work for customized labels:

[image]

How can I have a list like this without exceeding left boundary of the document :

```
        label 0: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                 XXXXXXXXXXXXX
     label long: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                 XXXXXXXXXXXXX
label long long: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                 XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I think I can achieve so by measuring the length of longest label name and play with `leftmargin` and `labelindent` but I wonder is there a smarter way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I rewrote this answer completely after the OP clarified his/her formatting objective.)

Since no enumeration occurs in the second list-like environment, don't use `enumerate`; instead, use a `description` environment, with the options `leftmargin=*` (an option you're already using), `align=right`, and `widest=\textbf{long long label}`.

[image]

Observe that, in a `description` environment, the optional arguments of `\item` are typeset in bold by default.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=*,
                    align=right,
                    widest=\textbf{long long label},]
\item[label] blah blah
\item[long label] blah
\item[long long label] \lipsum[75]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just noticed that the OP has clarified the formatting objective, after I had posted the  answer shown above. It would appear that I misunderstood the formatting objective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did take a look at package `description` but it doesn't look easy to make the list labels right aligned and list contents left aligned. (I just have question updated)

Comment: @Rahn - Would you like me to delete this answer since I completely misunderstood your formatting objective?

Comment: It's your answer so it's of course up to you.

Comment: @Rahn - I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, is `widest` a macro you defined? I got a "Undefined control sequence." for compiling your code (with XeLaTeX).

Comment: Did you mean `labelwidth=\widthof{\textbf{long long label}}`

Comment: @Rahn - The option `widest=<string>` is described on page 8 of the user guide of the `enumitem` package. (To open the user guide in a pdf viewer, open a command window and type `texdoc enumitem`.) Which TeX distribution do you employ? On mine -- MacTeX2020, all updates installed; enumitem version `2019/06/20 v3.9` -- the test document shown above compiles equally well under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Probably a version issue then. I'm using `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992` (TeX Live 2015), maybe too old. Never mind, I assume it works similarly as `labelwidth=\widthof{some text}`.

Comment: @Rahn - I would definitely look into moving up to TeXlive2020. Or, if updating a TeX distribution is a major chore, wait a few more weeks and upgrade to TeXlive 2021.